# React, optimize expensive components rendering time (blocking rendering)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, rendering

I have a two page in my SPA, let's say **Home** and **SongsList**.

In **SongsList** page I have a big component which list all my favourite songs (which are millions!).

So now when I click on the **SongsList** menu item (I'm using react-router) my browser freeze one moment before finish the rendering of the list component.

What I need is to render the page first (maybe also blank) and then, slowly and without blocking the page (maybe in other thread or in another way, this is what I'm asking) I can rendering the list of millions, billions songs.

**How to?**

Isn't React non-blocking prone?

Can I use web-workers?

What techniques for this problem?

**UPDATE**:

This is not a pagination problem. Let's say the list is small but I'm rendering heavy divs.

Comment: Is your page fast and responsive after you loaded all of the songs? Because I would guess that even scrolling that many elements is slow too.

Comment: You can implement pagination on both UI and API.

Comment: After the rendering everything is good. I just need to avoid this rendering problem. And not just for now. There is a best practice?

Comment: OK. This is not a pagination problem. Let's say the list is small but I'm rendering heavy divs. How to?

Comment: You could try rendering only a small amount of songs/divs/whatever in batches.
When one batch is rendered(componentDidMount fired) or the user scrolls down you append the next batch to your songlist.

Comment: @Maurice Döpke, can you explain it better? What are batches?

Comment: @JohnSam You could group for example 10 or whatever number of these list elements in group container component. This container components will be children of your list component.

In your list component you have some kind of state variable of how many group componets to render. You init this variable to 1 in your list components constructor.

Now from the group components lifecycle method: componentDidMount you call a method in your list component that increases this variable by one till all songs are rendered.

This should give your browser time to stay responsive during rendering.

Comment: @Maurice Döpke, can you link some example?

Comment: @JohnSam https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized

Maybe you can even directly use this project and don't need to reinvent the wheel.